# そういう君は～、 そういうおまえこそ～ - meaning?

Tags: meaning, modification

My guess it's a rude jargon thing (comes up a lot in anime and the like, used by male characters). What does it mean?

> A:　～～
> B:　そういう君は～ or そういうおまえこそ～

そう言う (そういう君 = "you who are talking like this..."), そういう (that kind of thing), or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common expression like 「そういう + Person + （こそ）」 has a few different meanings.  What the 「そういう」 part refers to depends entirely on the context.

Main Possibilities:

1. Someone has made a statement that you feel the need to address because it is not something you expected to hear and you want to come back at them.  「そういう」＝「そう言う」

> Woman: 「[謝]{あやま}りなさいよ！ (You made a f***in' **** outta me last night, you piece of ****in' ****!)」

> l'électeur: 「謝るかっ、ボケ！そういうお前こそオレに謝れ！ (You always *********!)」

2. Someone is being a certain way that you do not approve of and you want to make a comment about it. 「そういう」＝「そんな」

> 「(Explanation of how the listener has been to the speaker.)  そういうあなたがもういやになってしまったんです。」

3. The positive version of case 2).  You like the way someone is or has been and you want to make a comment about it. 「そういう」＝「そんな」

> 「(Explanation of the wonderful things the listener has done for the speaker over the years.)  そういう[君]{きみ}を[愛]{あい}している。[結婚]{けっこん}してほしい。」