# How is そういう + name used in this sentence?

Tags: reading-comprehension, questions

[image]

Upon being asked "What do you want to do/be in the future, the character answers the right part.

"For now I want to get out of this orphanage and live an enjoyable life"

To which the character then replies

具体性がない which is akin to "You are pretty superficial"

Then the character said

> そういうルカはあるのかよ

ルカ  then says he wants he wants to join the knights.

However what is going on with そういうルカはあるのかよ from context I can gather he's asking back the question "what do you want to do for the future on other hand?" but I don't see why そういう is being used here

The bubbles are a back and forth between the two characters and the character ルカ said the knights line and the 具体性がない line.

Comment: Dup? [そういう君は～、 そういうおまえこそ～ - meaning?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23469)

Comment: I'm not sure I would translate 具体性がない as *superficial*.  Rather, s/he doesn't specify anything concrete just "out of the orphanage" and "live an enjoyable life".  Those are vague, nonspecific aspirations; they aren't anything concrete.  To call them superficial, though, seems a bit odd.  Or those words could mean, "that'll never happen".

Answer (score 2):

- そう is "so" and 言う is "to say". そういう is a relative clause that modifies ルカ. A literal translation of そういうルカ is just "Luka, who says so". A bit verbose translation would be "As someone who says so, Luka, do you.."
- Just to be sure, ルカ is **not** the *subject* of ある although it's the (contrasted) *topic* of the sentence. The implicit *subject* that directly corresponds to ある is something like 将来やりたいこと or 将来の夢, which should have been mentioned in the previous context.

> そういうルカ**は**(将来やりたいこと**が**)あるのかよ。
> Do *you*, saying such things, have one (=a plan for the future)?